# Fix node position in tikzpicture between \only-slides in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-positioning

I want to show a graph on a beamer slide. However, using

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,semithick]

% Nodes
\node[draw,circle,fill=cyan!10] (v1) at (0, 0) {$-5$};
\node[draw,circle,fill=cyan!10] (t) at (2, 0) {$-1$};


% Edges
\only<1>{ \path (t) edge  node {$1$} (v1);}
\only<2>{ \path (t) edge  node {$1 / 2$} (v1);}


% Legend
\node[draw, rectangle, below] at (-1.5, -1) {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rcl@{}}
        \only<1->{Some text & : & A \\}      
        \only<2->{More text & : & B \\
        Even more & : & C}    
    \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
```

causes the nodes to move slightly in the northeast direction between the both slides generated by this.
I would much rather have the node positions fixed between the two slides while the legend somewhat changes.
Adding the `remember picture` parameter to the tikzpicture didn't help.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always include the class, the necessary packages and libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `\only`, I would use `\visible` and `visible on=` (the later is from the `overlay-beamer-styles` library). This way the content is still there on the other overlays, just not visible, which will avoid the jumping.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,semithick]

% Nodes
\node[draw,circle,fill=cyan!10] (v1) at (0, 0) {$-5$};
\node[draw,circle,fill=cyan!10] (t) at (2, 0) {$-1$};


% Edges
\path[visible on=<1>] (t) edge  node {$1$} (v1);
\path[visible on=<2>] (t) edge  node {$1 / 2$} (v1);


% Legend
\node[draw, rectangle, below] at (-1.5, -1) {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rcl@{}}
        \visible<1->{Some text & : & A \\}      
        \visible<2->{More text & : & B \\
        Even more & : & C}    
    \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]